# Keeping wrapped elements together

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several elements in HTML that I want to keep grouped when they wrap. I think the answer lies with some CSS (or maybe even JavaScript), but I'm not sure. For example, I have several elements laid out like this:

```
<label A><input A><label B><input B><label C><input C>
```

What happens is the users sometimes resize the browser window, and we end up with this:

```
<label A><input A><label B>
<input B><label C><input C>
```

In the example above, the input B isn't next to its input element. Is there a way to group the label and the input so they wrap together? I've tried divs and putting the elements together in a table with "nowrap", with mixed results. I don't mind the lines wrapping, I just need to keep the label and input element together.

Comment: I know this is an old one, but could you post your solution please?

Comment: Wow, sorry I just saw your comment. I don't have this source anymore, but try things in the answers below. That's all I did. HTH :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may also be worth looking at setting parent divs around each pair you wish to keep together - I know you said you tried this but also give them a fixed width and display:inline; and it should work

ALSOO include float:left/right;(choose only one) This way, if the browser window is too small to show them all side by side, it will instead take the end pair and drop it onto the next line but should keep all elements within together and side by side.

Comment: Fooled with this some, and finally got it. Thanks a **ton**! It also solved some other rendering problems the page was experiencing.

Answer (score 19):

Try something like this:

```
<label>First Name:
    <input type="text">
</label>
<label>Last Name:
    <input type="text">
</label>
```

and set

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo http://dabblet.com/gist/3145028

Alternative: wrap both `<label>` and `<input>` in a `<div>` with `display: inline-block`

Comment: Thanks, Ana! I love this solution: simple and elegant! Plus a demo so I can see it in action! Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. This page has TONS of CSS, and something else in the CSS is preventing it from working properly. :(

Comment: Could you detail a bit on that? Maybe edit your original question with how it behaved when you tried the alternatives in the answers.

Answer (score 8):

The simple answer is to wrap elements into another element that has a display: inline-block as a style. So...

```
<span class='wrapper'>
  <span class='left-side'></span>
  <span class='right-side'></span>
</span>
```

And

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Put all of those elements in a div like this:

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I did try that. It has no effect at all. :( The elements still break apart.

Answer (score 0):

You could put each label/input group in a `<span>` and then set the css to `display:inline`. I am pretty sure this will keep it grouped. Depending on your site layout and previous CSS, you may  have to tweak the span css.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said this was in a table, here is probably what you were looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/DX9G7/

HTML:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="30%" />
        <col width="30%" />
        <col width="40%" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label>A</label>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label>B</label>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label>C</label>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

You can now modify your css the way you want.